# Send array of objects in a file as attachment back to the client

Tags: node.js, express

I have a system where a user can upload a `txt` file from the browser, and the data from this file is parsed on the server and used to perform more logic and additional operations. Once all the operations are complete, I want to send back an `txt` file to the client to be received as an attachment.

The data inside the `output.txt` is object payload with each line representing an payload. I am storing all the data in an array of objects

```
let finalData = [{},{},{},....,{}]
```

I have the following, but not sure if its right

```
    res.set({'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=\"output.txt\"','Content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.status(200).send(finalData);
```

The **output.txt** should look like the following

```
{"id":"6371","customer_id":"375","accepted":true}
{"id":"15265","customer_id":"18","accepted":true}
{"id":"8592","customer_id":"494","accepted":true}
...
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't just send JSON?

Comment: @Anatoly could please clarify? do you mean res.send(JSON.stringify(finalData))

Comment: I mean `res.json(finalData)`

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick:

```
let finalData = [{},{},{},....,{}];
res.set({'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=\"output.txt\"','Content-type': 'text/plain'});
res.send(JSON.stringify(finalData));
```